# passing GtkWidget parameters

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have a function that is connected to the "changed" signal for a combobox in gtk, which in turn calls another function read_button_config.

The read_button_config takes the main window, a combobox and a vcontainer which I had not declared globally as parameters

Which way is better for passing these parameters:
- declaring the parameters globally
- passing the parameters as a struct to the first function, and passing the struct members to the read_button_config function?

Please let me know why you think either is better, I want to know what is a better way for future development

Comment: The latter is the preferred way; that is the purpose of the `user_data` parameter to signal functions, after all.

Comment: why though, I never got the reason behind that

Comment: What do you mean, why you need `user_data` parameters? Or are you confused about something else? And are you familiar with any other GUI toolkits besides GTK+ or programming languages other than C? (This last question may help me make explaining the situation easier.)

Comment: I meant why is declaring them globally something bad, I'm familiar with Java and cpp, and I'm familiar with no other gui toolkits

Comment: Declaring them globally isn't *bad*. Rather, using the `user_data` is *idiomatic*. It's a bit harder since you have to manage the memory for the `user_data` yourself, but using `user_data` keeps your code modules more self-contained. You will need to decide what you want to do.

Comment: perfect, just the answer I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Which way is better for passing these parameters: - declaring the
>   parameters globally - passing the parameters as a struct to the first
>   function, and passing the struct members to the read_button_config
>   function?

The latter is the preferred way; that is the purpose of the `user_data` parameter to signal functions, after all.
Declaring them globally isn't *bad*. Rather, using the `user_data` is *idiomatic*. It's a bit harder since you have to manage the memory for the `user_data` yourself, but using `user_data` keeps your code modules more self-contained. You will need to decide what you want to do.
                    – andlabs